# How can I set-mark in Clink Bash's command line editing to Microsoft Windows' cmd.exe

Tags: bash, emacs, cmd

There is a useful **Сlink** https://code.google.com/p/clink/ tool to improve windows CMD.

One can see key bindings after pressing <kbd>ALT+H</kbd>. Very first combination is set-command bound to <kbd>C+@</kbd>.

What does <kbd>@</kbd> means here? <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+2</kbd> won't work.

People who use Emacs probably can help me, because I can see the same key binding in Emacs documentation.

Comment: Have you tried C-SPACE?  I know is different, but in emacs it is bound to the same function than c-@ (that being said, either the documentation of Clink is not accurate, or your "window manager" could be stealing that key combination)

Answer (score 0):

Either Ctrl-2 or Ctrl-Shift-2 will work. You set the mark with C-@ and then later use C-x,C-x to move the cursor back to the mark. Repeating C-x,C-x will swap the cursor between the two positions.